# Logic error resulting in missing/incorrect output possibly relative to for-loop

Tags: java, oop, for-loop, logic, output

The `PrimeDetector` class shown below has documentation which describes the uses of each method. The tester class creates an object of the `PrimeDetector` class and attempts to print a set of generated integer values from an ArrayList returned from the `hasPrime()` method. I do not see my error, as I have created a procedural version of it which works just fine. It prints only the first 3 prime numbers, and returns as having only detected 3 prime numbers--leading me to believe that the issue lies within the `PrimeDetector` class, somewhere within the for-loop, though I can't be certain, as it is nearly the same structure as my procedural version--so far as I can tell. I will include the single procedural  class, as well as the OOP version and its tester.

```
/**
 * The PrimeDetector class detects prime numbers within a user's
 * given set [0,n] where n is a user-given upper limit.
 * 
 * @author A. Mackey
 * @version 06/05/14
 */
import java.util.*;
public class PrimeDetector {
    private int n;
    private int primeCounter;
    private ArrayList<Integer> primeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class PrimeDetector
     * @param n is the upper limit in the set [0,n] tested with the hasPrime() method.
     */
    public PrimeDetector(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    /**
     * @return an ArrayList of type Integer containing all prime values within the set [0,n].
     */
    public ArrayList<Integer> hasPrime() {
        primeCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            boolean isPrime = true;
            for (int j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isPrime) {
                primeCounter++;
                primeList.add(i);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return primeList;
    }

    /**
     * @return primeCounter variable which holds and integer value equivalent to the number of prime values in
     * the [0,n] set evaluated in the hasPrime() method.
     */
    public int getPrimeCounter() {
        return primeCounter;
    }
}
```

Tester:

```
/**
 * The PrimeDetectorTest class tests the PrimeDetector class, which detects prime numbers within a user's
 * given set [0,n] where n = a user-given upper limit.
 * 
 * @author A. Mackey
 * @version 06/05/14
 */
import java.util.*;
public class PrimeDetectorTest
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer you wish to find primes up to: ");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The following list is prime within the range [0, " + n + "]: ");
        PrimeDetector list = new PrimeDetector(n);

        ArrayList<Integer> primeList = list.hasPrime();

        for (int s : primeList)
        {
            System.out.println(s + " is prime.");
        }

        System.out.println(list.getPrimeCounter() + " prime numbers within this set.");
    }
}
```

Procedural version:

```
import java.util.*;
public class PrimeDetectorV1
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer you wish to find primes up to: ");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int primeCounter = 0;
        System.out.println("The following list is prime within the range [0, " + n + "]: ");

        for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            while (i>0)
            {
                boolean isPrime = true;
                for (int j = 2; j <= i/2; j++)
                {
                    if(i % j == 0)
                    {
                        isPrime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isPrime)
                {
                    System.out.println(i + " is prime.");
                    primeCounter++;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("There are " + primeCounter + " prime numbers within this set.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  if (isPrime) {
      primeCounter++;
      primeList.add(i);
  } else {
       break;
  }
```

Remove the `else{break;}` here. Because if you found a number that is not prime, you still need to check the next one. Currently your program will stop when it founds a number that is not prime.

Also 1 is not a prime number so you should start your first loop at 2.

Comment: Hey, good on ya mate. Works perfectly. Care to expand on the logic behind that error a bit more? So the break causes it to stop when finding a number not prime, but--I would expect it to begin searching the next value of i for primality.

Comment: @alx The `break;` will cause the loop `for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {` to stop. So yes let's say you want to find the prime numbers in `[2, 5]` when you'll test 4, you'll found that it's not prime, setting `isPrime` to `false` and breaking the outer loop. You could use `continue;` instead to tell ok continue the loop for the next step without caring of what is after the statement, but I don't recommend to do this. Just remove the `else`.

Comment: I'm mainly curious--as it doesn't at all break my procedural version.

Comment: @alx Because in your procedural version you are breaking the `while`, not the outer `for`. So you keep go to the next number to check (actually your while is useless because you never decrement `i` inside it, you just add another layer of looping and you'll have to break the infinite loop you created).

Comment: I'm a bit new to the use of `break`--why does it not negatively affect the looping process in the if statement, but does in the else--and why was it non-affective in my procedural version?

Comment: Oh, that makes perfect sense--I see. But why does it positively affect the searching process in my if, but not my else?

Comment: @alx You mean here `if (i % j == 0) {isPrime = false;break;}`? With no label associated, `break` breaks the innermost loop. So if `i%j == 0`, the number you're testing is not prime, so there is no need to do more iterations, you can go directly testing the next.